# Java ArrayList's merge function complexity

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o

I had to write a function that merges two given sorted (from smallest to largest) ArrayList's of Integer's. Merge must be done in the first ArraList (in our case list ***a***) and we must leave the sorted order(from smallest to largest).

```
 void merge(ArrayList<Integer> a, ArrayList<Integer> b) {
    int currentIndexListA = 0;
    int currentIndexListB = 0;

    while(currentIndexListB < b.size()) {
        if(currentIndexListA == a.size() || a.get(currentIndexListA) > b.get(currentIndexListB)) {
            a.add(currentIndexListA, b.get(currentIndexListB));
            currentIndexListB++;
        }
        currentIndexListA++;
    }
}
```

So, i'm a few confusing about complexity of algorithm. The task was to make the maximum efficiency algorithm  with complexity of O(N). And I think that it's O(N) complexity, but the interviewer responded that the code is **inefficient**. Is it correct ?

Comment: are the lists LinkedLists?

Comment: I thought about this.. about costs of shifting elements after adding in ArrayList etc. But given lists are ArrayLists. And we should operate with them. For clarity i edited function signature.

Comment: yeah if these are ArrayLists, as you said, *add* shifts the elements and it is definitely not O(N), you could create a new ArrayList and merge and finally clear *a* and add all elements of merged list to *a*

Comment: @SomeDude thank you, now i understood. Maybe my problem was that I thought I needed to manipulate only with two given ArrayList's without the help of others...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used ***ArrayList.add*** function by index which insert your data at specified position and shift other elements. `add` function in **ArrayList** class uses `System.arraycopy` to shift elements and `System.arraycopy` uses native implementation with O(N) which N is the number of shifted elements. So you algorithm is not efficient.

A better way as @SomeDude said is using new ArrayList such as following:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main
{
    static void merge2(ArrayList<Integer> a, ArrayList<Integer> b) {
        
        ArrayList<Integer> c = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int ixa=0, ixb=0;
        int limita = a.size();
        int limitb = b.size();
        int aElem = 0;
        int bElem = 0;
        
        while(ixa+ixb < limita+limitb ) {
            
            aElem = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            bElem = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            
            if(ixa < limita) 
                aElem = a.get(ixa);
            
            if(ixb < limitb)
                bElem = b.get(ixb);
                
            if( aElem <= bElem) {
                c.add(aElem);
                ixa++;
            }else {
                c.add(bElem);
                ixb++;
            }
        }

        
        for(Integer aa:c) {
            System.out.println(aa);
        }
    
    }

     public static void main(String []args){
        ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,3,5));
        ArrayList<Integer> b = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(2,4,6));
        
        merge2(a,b);
        
        ArrayList<Integer> c = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
        ArrayList<Integer> d = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(5,6,7));

        merge2(c,d);
     }
}
```

Comment: I thought according to OP "merge must be done in the first ArrayList".

Comment: If it was a linked list it is possible with O(N), but because of shift operation it gives more complexity. However someone can add the second list at the end of the first list and use a sort algorithm like insertion sort to sort all list. Which cause more complexity.

Comment: @majidhajibaba I think that the main problem of this task in what is written to put the result in first ArrayList. I even didn't think about using anything else other than two given ArrayList's, I decided that all operations should be done in first ArrayList. But most likely expected use of one more ArrayList for merging.